# Fitting pipeline and processing the data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipeline

I've got a file that contains text. What I want to do is to use a pipeline for tokenising the text, removing the stop-words and producing 2-grams.

What I've done so far:

**Step 1: Read the file**

```
val data = sparkSession.read.text("data.txt").toDF("text")
```

**Step 2: Build the pipeline**

```
val pipe1 = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
val pipe2 = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered")
val pipe3 = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("ngrams")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(pipe1, pipe2, pipe3))
val model = pipeline.fit(data)
```

I know that `pipeline.fit(data)` produces a `PipelineModel` however I don't know how to use a `PipelineModel`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `val model = pipeline.fit(data)` code, all `Estimator` stages (ie: Machine Learning tasks like Classifications, Regressions, Clustering, etc) are fit to the data and a `Transformer` stage is created.  You only have `Transformer` stages, since you're doing Feature creation in this pipeline.

In order to execute your model, now consisting of just `Transformer` stages, you need to run `val results = model.transform(data)`.  This will execute each `Transformer` stage against your dataframe.  Thus at the end of the `model.transform(data)` process, you will have a dataframe consisting of the original lines, the Tokenizer output, the StopWordsRemover output, and finally the NGram results.

Discovering the top 5 ngrams after the feature creation is completed can be performed through a SparkSQL query.  First explode the ngram column, then count groupby ngrams, ordering by the counted column in a descending fashion, and then performing a `show(5)`.  Alternatively, you could use a `"LIMIT 5` method instead of `show(5)`.

As an aside, you should probably change your Object name to something that isn't a standard class name.  Otherwise you're going to get an ambigious scope error.

**CODE:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.NGram
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}

object NGramPipeline {
    def main() {
        val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("NGram Pipeline").getOrCreate()

        val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

        val data = sparkSession.read.text("quangle.txt").toDF("text")

        val pipe1 = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
        val pipe2 = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered")
        val pipe3 = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("ngrams")

        val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(pipe1, pipe2, pipe3))
        val model = pipeline.fit(data)

        val results = model.transform(data)

        val explodedNGrams = results.withColumn("explNGrams", explode($"ngrams"))
        explodedNGrams.groupBy("explNGrams").agg(count("*") as "ngramCount").orderBy(desc("ngramCount")).show(10,false)

    }
}
NGramPipeline.main()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+-----------------+----------+
|explNGrams       |ngramCount|
+-----------------+----------+
|quangle wangle   |9         |
|wangle quee.     |4         |
|'mr. quangle     |3         |
|said, --         |2         |
|wangle said      |2         |
|crumpetty tree   |2         |
|crumpetty tree,  |2         |
|quangle wangle,  |2         |
|crumpetty tree,--|2         |
|blue babboon,    |2         |
+-----------------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Notice that there is syntax (commas, dashes, etc) which are causing lines to be duplicated.  When performing ngrams, it's often a good idea to filter our the syntax.  You can typically do this with a regex.

Comment: For specific details on what I mean by a "Transformer", you can read the "How It Works" section of the Pipeline doc.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#how-it-works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please also explain what should I do in order to get the 5 most frequent 2-grams? In the code you've added, the first 5 2-grams are shown (and not the 5 most-frequent).

Comment: Sure, that's just sql query once the ngram feature has been created.  It's added to the example.

Comment: These were ngram pairs, so one pair was (quangle wangle, qangle quee), and another pair was (quangle wangle, wangle said).

Comment: You're looking for the explode function, then.  Sorry, misunderstood.  I'll update the example with the explode.